# PHP SoapClient: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, soap-client

I'm making what's likely to be a really simple mistake but can't seem to work out. I'm attempting to send a SOAP request to a web service using the PHP SoapClient library. The following error occurs when attempting to print:

> "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Here is the code, taken primarily from the PHP SoapClient Manual.

```
<?php

try { 
    $options = array( 
                     'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2, 
                     'exceptions'=>true, 
                     'trace'=>1, 
                     'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE 
                    ); 
    $client = new SoapClient('http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertTemperature.asmx?WSDL', $options); 

    $results = $client->ConvertTemp(array('Temperature'=>'100', 'FromUnit' => 'degreeCelsius',
                                          'ToUnit' => 'degreeFahrenheit')); 
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    { 
      echo "<h2>Exception Error!</h2>"; 
      echo $e->getMessage(); 
    } 

$results = $client->ConvertTemp(array('Temperature'=>'100', 'FromUnit' => 'degreeCelsius',
                                    'ToUnit' => 'degreeFahrenheit')); 

print $results;
?>
```

I understand that the message is telling me that I'm trying to print an entire object rather than a member of that object. What I don't understand is that I'm expecting a call to ConvertTemp to return a string. Why is an object being return? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your expectations may be wrong. A `var_dump` or `print_r` can shed light on what `$results` actually is, re-examing the wsdl could tell you why:

Hint: `__getTypes()`:

```
struct ConvertTempResponse {
 double ConvertTempResult;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You're correct. I now see the call is being returned as an object. Now treating $results as an object, I'm having trouble accessing the member, ConvertTempResult. Perhaps my syntax is incorrect. I'm using 'print $results->ConvertTempResult', however I'm now receiving an "Undefined variable" error.

Comment: With the rest of the code kept the same, `print $results->ConvertTempResult;` works here... Are you sure you haven't changed anything else?

Comment: Well, I guess it's good to know it's at least working somewhere. The code is the same with the only difference being the reference to the member variable. I think this may be moving off the original topic so I don't think I'll drag the thread out here anymore. If the code is working then most likely something is wrong with my setup, maybe server settings (XAMPP), firewall, something. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'd persist for a little while... If you get an object back and not a fatal exception, most likely the whole SOAP side of things worked. 'undefined variable' seems to me most probably a simple unrelated typo in either variable- or attribute names....

Comment: You nailed it, typo. Although I wrote '$results' previously, '$result' was actually what was written in the code. Everything is working correctly now. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: Very useful functions $client->__getFunctions() and $client->__getTypes(), Thanks to both of you.